# Math.round(msgBody.length() / 160 + 0.5) Not Evaluating Correctly?

Tags: java, android, math, rounding

So I'm trying to dynamically calculate the number of SMS messages that will be sent for a given message length.  SMS messages are chunked into 160 byte (character) chunks.  I use MOD 160 <= 1 because I need to account for adding and subtracting text.  For performance reasons I only want to do the numMsgs calculations near the boundaries: 0, 1, 160, 161, 320, 321, ...

The problem is at a msgBody length of 160 the rounding operation evaluates to 2 (160/160 = 1 + 0.5 rounded up).  At multiples of 160 + 1 it should evaluate to the next highest integer because any 160 bytes + 1 byte equals a whole additional message.

I have made this work by using an OR operator and == 1 OR == 159.  It increments and decrements correctly, but it only decrements at multiples of 160 -1 which is not correct.

Also, I can put IF logic inside the outer logic to simply subtract 1 if the MOD evaluates to 0 (zero), but that seemed kludgey and I'd rather learn the pattern I may be missing from my quiver :)

```
if (msgBody.length() % 160 <= 1) {

    numMsgs.setText(Math.round(msgBody.length() / 160 + 0.5));

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`msgBody.length() / 160` is a division expressions with both sides being *integers* - so it will perform *integer* division. I *suspect* that's what you're doing wrong, but it's not entirely clear to be honest. (You claim it's not evaluating correctly, but you haven't given a sample input / output / expected output for us to look at.)

To be honest, the simplest approach is to round up like this:

```
numMsgs.setText((msgBody.length() + 159) / 160);
```

That's still performing integer division, but the +159 means it will round up if the input isn't *exactly* a multiple of 160.

I suggest you could perform that calculation *regardless* of the boundaries - but make sure you don't actually update the UI if there's no change compared with the existing value. It's going to be very cheap - one integer add and one integer divide.

Comment: Jon, your solution is better than mine.

Comment: Integer.valueOf((msgBody.length() + 159)/160);  That works perfectly.

Comment: @Bill Mote: You shouldn't need to call `Integer.valueOf` explicitly - autoboxing should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a message, then at least 1 SMS will be sent. 
You want

```
      (length / 160) + (length%160 > 0 ? 1 : 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding and dividing using `int` is enough with the right formula. Modulo is probably even slower than dividing. However, it's not clear to me what result you expect... `(msgBody.length() + 159) / 160` isn't enough?

Comment: The number of SMS to send - 1 for each 160 characters plus 1 for the remaining characters. The formula (159+length)/ 160 computes exactly this.